# Unicorn Voting - Bringing the Joy of April 1 All Year 'Round!

Tags: script, voting

[image]

### About

They're back! Although they were created for April 1<sup>st</sup>, you can now enjoy them throughout the whole year! Simply install this UserScript and commence upvoting and downvoting.

#### License

[The Unicorn Software License](http://quickmediasolutions.com/unicorn)

#### Download

This script is available as a UserScript:
http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/userscripts/vote.user.js

*Simply click the link above to install the script in Chrome. Firefox users need to have the GreaseMonkey extension installed.*

#### Platform

All UserScript capable browsers.

### Contact

I can be contacted at `admin@quickmediasolutions.com`

### Code

Written in jQuery using the JavaScript plugin... no wait - that doesn't seem quite right.

Answer (score 6):

## [Unicorn Starring](https://github.com/rlemon/UserScripts/tree/master/StackExchange/UnicornStarring)

*a userscript to bring unicorns to chat stars!*

Only uses the OP images.
Same License. <sub>*Don't sue me George*</sub>

[Install](https://github.com/rlemon/UserScripts/raw/master/StackExchange/UnicornStarring/unicorns.user.js)

Comment: *"I'm suing you!"* Just kidding - nice UserScript.

Answer (score 5):

I recreated a few more of the original animations as GIFs on imgur (from the [static pngs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/85617/can-we-get-a-gallery-of-unicorns/85618#85618)). To use them, just replace the `if(vote_up) {}` block in above userjs with:

```
var animations = [
    // down
    [                        //  url    top  height
        ['https://i.imgur.com/BhbcF.gif', 65, 116], 
        ['https://i.imgur.com/notGT.gif', 75, 108],    // duplict BhbcF
        ['https://i.imgur.com/qbHhb.gif', 50, 100],    // was 1Fba1.png
        ['https://i.imgur.com/Xqezn.gif', 50, 114],    // was RXgxY.png
        ['https://i.imgur.com/NI5WN.gif', 50, 102],    // was xBS3c.png
    ],
    // up
    [
        ['https://i.imgur.com/EhQXl.gif', 20, 125],
        ['https://i.imgur.com/ZS0pZ.gif', 25, 100],    // was 1XY5D.png
        ['https://i.imgur.com/rPqDf.gif', 35, 101],    // was 4q8j8.png
        ['https://i.imgur.com/F8N9Y.gif', 35, 150],    // was cBop8.png
        ['https://i.imgur.com/Qetgr.gif', 35, 120],    // was cMyYU.png
    ]
];   
var pick = animations[vote_up ? 1 : 0][parseInt(Math.random()*5)];
var url = pick[0];
var top = pick[1];
var height = pick[2];
```

It could use some extra parameters for positioning and non-default image widths, but OTOH there is no need to overdo it.

(Still amusing. And all the more useful now that we have +10 question upvotes.)